# Отправка данных формы на почту

Tags: wordpress, form, acf

Интегрировал верстку на вп через плагин ACF, пробовал привязать форму через плагин easy WP SMTP, но не вышло(возможно из-за того что провожу тесты на локальном сервере). Подскажите как отправить форму на почту

Comment: Использовать плагины для форм. Например CF7. ЗЫ. "верстка через ACF"... ОМГ...